# Android video on demand and remote control

Tags: android, communication

I am going to start a project on video-on-demand application on Android. Basically I want the Android device to require video from a streamer (vlc or others, not limited) and the streamer could respond. However, I don't know where to start this project and which knowledge are needed. So anyone please advice.

Thanks a lot.

Charlie

Comment: Clarify if VOD or real time streaming (RTP). Two different animals, the latter more complicated.

Comment: Hi,user247245. My initial plan is just to develop VOD, but I am not sure about the difference about these two. Can you elaborate more on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaPlayer API's call the PVPlayer itself...[pvplayer guide](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/1.6/external/opencore/doc/pv2way_developers_guide.pdf)

this document should be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks garima, but I have a question. Since it seems that MediaPlayer.java uses PVPlayer internally, how can I use it at Android application level?

Comment: In other words, I already have the whole "opencore" directory in my PC, but I don't know how to play with it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all which android version are you working on? are you using the PVplayer to display the video? you can you the sample test of PVplayer..test number 6 to play a SDP file..u can go through the documentation of pvplayer tests. ..u can setup the VLC player as RTSP server ..I have tried this.. it works.. make your application an .apk and try to play live stream..

Comment: Hi garima, I am using Android 1.5 platform (G1) and I am using MediaPlayer API to display/stream video. I am not sure what PVplayer is and how it is related to VOD. Can you explain a little more? Or Can you provide some useful links? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Charlie. you won't be able to use PVplayer at the application level. but still you would be able to pass RTSP url directly in your Media Player API startPlayer..I think you should explore the C code instead of Application level.